# Use pointer as output parameter of a method in objective c

Tags: objective-c, pointers

I defined one method whose declaration looks like below:

```
- (BOOL) loadMesh: (Mesh *)mesh fromFile: (NSString *)fileName;
```

I intend it to load one Mesh object from the given file, so the pointer "mesh" is used as the output parameter. But "mesh" is always "nil", although inside the method it's not "nil". I think it is because ARC released the memory that "mesh" points to when leaving the method.

Is there anyway to solve this problem other than using Mesh* as the return value of the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `Mesh` as a class, so `mesh` is an object, right? And you are trying to set it like this:

```
- (BOOL)loadMesh:(Mesh *)mesh fromFile:(NSString *)fileName
{
    mesh = // some code
    return YES;
}

Mesh *m = nil;
[self loadMesh:m fromFile:@"foo"];
```

However, `mesh`, being a function argument, is local to the function and is not visible outside its scope. You have to use a pointer to it and set it through the pointer, like this:

```
- (BOOL)loadMesh:(Mesh **)mesh fromFile:(NSString *)fileName
{
    *mesh = theMesh;
    return YES;
}

Mesh *m = nil;
[self loadMesh:&m fromFile:@"foo"];
```